# Bundled composer.json in CakePHP/2.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, composer-php

The CakePHP/2.6 download includes a [top-level `composer.json` file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7/composer.json):

```
{
    "name": "cakephp/cakephp",
    "description": "The CakePHP framework",
    "type": "library",
    "keywords": ["framework"],
    "homepage": "http://cakephp.org",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "CakePHP Community",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/graphs/contributors"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues",
        "forum": "http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cakephp",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.org/cakephp",
        "source": "https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.2.8",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
        "cakephp/debug_kit" : "2.2.*"
    },
    "bin": [
        "lib/Cake/Console/cake"
    ]
}
```

However, when I run `composer install` stuff gets installed in newly created folders that don't seem to follow the CakePHP convention:

- `Plugin` instead of `plugins`
- `vendor` instead of `vendors`

... and I end up with this:

```
07/01/2015  12:41    <DIR>          Plugin
07/01/2015  12:38    <DIR>          plugins
07/01/2015  12:41    <DIR>          vendor
07/01/2015  12:38    <DIR>          vendors
```

I'm fairly new to both technologies (CakePHP and Composer) so I wonder if I'm missing something obvious. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: For CakePHP 2.x "Plugin" and "vendor" are the correct composer folders (outside APP dir). Otherwise you need to manually specify them. See https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/app-template . If you use APP==ROOT, see https://github.com/dereuromark/cakefest/tree/master for an example.

Comment: @mark - Ah, alright... Any idea why [initial layout](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.7) has `plugins` and `vendors`?

Comment: Because thats the ROOT dir, and there its plugins and vendors. The APP dir contains Plugin and Vendor. Once you use composer you should chose either root or non root layout and then stick to only one folder system (either vendor/plugins or Vendor/Plugin).

Comment: @mark - Not sure I follow you now. Does Composer use different folders than CakePHP for **root** dir? Is it due to a limitation on either sides?

Comment: In Cake2 it does, in Cake3 this is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using the "extra" and "config" option. In the "extra" section i put the plugins and where i want to place them and in the "config" section i tell to composer that my vendor dir is "app/Vendor".

Like the following composer.json

```
{
"name": "cakephp/cakephp",
"description": "The CakePHP framework",
"type": "library",
"keywords": ["framework"],
"homepage": "http://cakephp.org",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "CakePHP Community",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/graphs/contributors"
    }
],
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues",
    "forum": "http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cakephp",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.org/cakephp",
    "source": "https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp"
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "ext-mcrypt": "*",
    "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "2.5.*",
    "minishlink/web-push": "^1.4"
},
"require-dev": {
    "cakephp/debug_kit": "^2.2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.38",
    "cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer": "^1.0.0"
},
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "app/Plugin/DebugKit": ["cakephp/debug_kit"]
    }
},
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "app/Vendor"
},
"bin": [
    "lib/Cake/Console/cake"
]
}
```